# Installation SystemC 2.3.2 failed

Tags: installation, ubuntu-16.04, systemc

I want to install SystemC 2.3.2 on ubuntu 16.04 So i followd the install file directives:

```
  2. Create a temporary directory, e.g.,

        > mkdir objdir

  3. Change to the temporary directory, e.g.,

        > cd objdir

  4. Choose your compiler by setting the CXX environment variable

        > export CXX=g++


  5. Configure the package for your system, e.g.,
     (The configure script is explained below.)

        > ../configure

     In case you want to install the package in another place than the
     top level directory (systemc-2.3.2), configure the package e.g. as
     follows:

        > ../configure --prefix=/usr/local/systemc-2.3.2

  6. Compile the package.

        > make

  7. At this point you may wish to verify the compiled package by
     testing the example suite.

        > make check

  8. Install the package.

        > make install

  9. You can now remove the temporary directory, .e.g,

        > cd ..
        > rm -rf objdir
```

every step went good until i reached step 8 to install the package ... i get the following error:

```
user@user-Lenovo-IdeaPad-Y510P:~/systemc-2.3.2/objdir$ make install
Making install in docs
make[1]: Entering directory '/home/anoir/systemc-2.3.2/objdir/docs'
make[2]: Entering directory '/home/anoir/systemc-2.3.2/objdir/docs'
make[2]: Nothing to be done for 'install-exec-am'.
 /bin/mkdir -p '/usr/local/systemc-2.3.2/docs'
/bin/mkdir: cannot create directory ‘/usr/local/systemc-2.3.2’: Permission denied
Makefile:380: recipe for target 'install-nobase_docDATA' failed
make[2]: *** [install-nobase_docDATA] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/anoir/systemc-2.3.2/objdir/docs'
Makefile:453: recipe for target 'install-am' failed
make[1]: *** [install-am] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/anoir/systemc-2.3.2/objdir/docs'
Makefile:505: recipe for target 'install-recursive' failed
make: *** [install-recursive] Error 1
```

I don't understand the problem. What could be my mistake

Answer (score 1):

Default install location need `root` access. If you don't have it. Try to install it to other location which you have right to access.

For example:

```
../configure --prefix ${HOME}/SystemC
```